What accents are used to represent the various factions in audiobooks for the Shadows of the Apt series?
In the audiobooks Ben Allen is the narrator, and each city/kinden seems to have a distinct accents (except Collegium and the Wasp Empire, where each character seems to be distinct) many of which are from the United Kingdom.
For example, the characters from the one of the ant cities consistently have a scouse accent, the spiderlands have various American accents (contrast Tynisa vs Taki-Amre).
Adrian Tchaikovsky has made use of these accents in other Audiobooks like with Haever Mundy having a brummie accent in The Final Architecture series, albeit with a different narrator (Sophie Aldred).
So this feels like a deliberate and consistent choice.
What are all the accents used to represent the various factions in audiobooks for the Shadows of the Apt series?
